# Character '&' in XML Parsing iphone

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I am using NSXMLParsing to parse an XML , whose formatting is not in my control

From XML it seems it's using UTF-8 encoding, however i get illegal character encoding error when a character like '&' comes into picture.

Due to this i have to go the dirty way of breaking strings and parsing.

Any way out?

Suggestions ?

Thanks
Yogurt

Comment: Not at all irrelevant. You're lucky I gave even the small answer I did. Nobody likes to answer a question when they know the asker won't be giving them any rep.

Comment: Alright, I Apologise if things don't seem right. However, of the 9 Questions, Has Marc seen how many ended upto a logical end...my analysis tells me it's 1...

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have malformed XML. "&" is the start of an entity in XML, e.g. `&amp;` or `&lt;`. Having a raw "&" by itself that doesn't match an entity is illegal.

Comment: Yeah....from XML it seems so it's a malformed XML, since the XML outputted is not under my control, any way out other than the string breaking thing..